# why NSTimer works just once in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a http request, and if I receive the response correctly, then I want to start a timer that fires a function each second. That function is also a http request.

this is my code to fire the timer

```
    if let data = data {
        do{
            let resultJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
            requestClient.id = resultJSON["id"] as! Double
            self.timerResponse = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "checkIfThereAreResponeses", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            self.timerResponse!.fire()
        }catch{
        }
    }
```

as you see, I'm calling a function called `checkIfThereAreResponses`

In that function, i have a print statement, and that print statement is being printed just once, **though my timer supposed to work each 1 second**

what missing i have?

And this is the function

```
 func checkIfThereAreResponeses(){
    if (requestClient!.id != nil) {
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:blablabla")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("error = \(error)")
            }



            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let resultJSONArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as! NSArray
        bla bla bla

                }catch {
                    print("no responses yet = \(error)")
                }
            }
        })
        task!.resume()
    }else {
        print("not yet ")
    }
}
```

the print that i receive **JUST ONCE** is the `no response yet`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, is the `print` the first statement inside `checkIfThereAreResponeses`?

Comment: @luk2302 yet it is inside it.

Comment: but is it the *first*? Might be helpful to see the actual `checkIfThereAreResponeses`!

Comment: @luk2302 Okay I gave you the code

Comment: @luk2302 i put now a print at the begining of the function, it still work  just once, but when i put the timer in the main thread it works

Comment: Okay, that is a new issue to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have this code in completion handler, it is recommended NSTimer is running in the main thread so this could be the reason. You might need something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    // Your timer logic here
})
```

Apple docs say:

> Timers work in conjunction with run loops. To use a timer effectively,
>   you should be aware of how run loops operate—see NSRunLoop.

([NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/))

> The NSRunLoop class is generally not considered to be thread-safe and
>   its methods should only be called within the context of the current
>   thread. You should never try to call the methods of an NSRunLoop
>   object running in a different thread, as doing so might cause
>   unexpected results.

([NSRunLoop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSRunLoop))

Comment: are you impling to change my code to `                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.timerResponse = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "checkIfThereAreResponeses", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                        self.timerResponse!.fire()
                        }
                    )` ?

Comment: @sarah yes, something like that is the implication of the answer.

Comment: can i have a link to increase my knowledge in this problem plase ?

Comment: It is not really recommended to run an NSTimer in the main thread, it is just convenient. An NSTimer can run on a runloop on any thread, you just need to be aware of the lifetime of that thread. The main thread is convenient as it will never die unless your application dies. It is important to realize that when the timer fires, the selector is called on the thread which has the runloop that runs the timer.

Answer (score 2):

An NSTimer works by being scheduled on a runloop. If you call this method in the completionHandler of the session, it will be scheduled to the runloop of the thread that that completionHandler is currently running on. As this thread is not owned by you, but by the system, it will be disposed of by the system. This might be immediately after the completionHandler is done executing, or it might be much later. With the thread, the runloop is gone too, thus, your timer might fire never, a couple of times or just once; there is no telling really as it depends on when the system will remove the thread.

Therefore, you should create the timer on a thread you own, or, easier, dispatch the creation of the timer to the main thread (`dispatch_get_main_queue()` is your friend). Another option is to create an NSTimer with one of the `+timerWithTimeInterval...` methods and then add it to the main runloop using `[NSRunloop mainRunloop] addTimer: yourTimer forMode NSRunLoopCommonModes]`. Remember that the timer will call your selector on the same thread as the the runloop it runs on.

As a side note, polling a server might not be the best way to go on a mobile device. If you control the server, it might be better to send a push notification to the device when there is new data for it. This will save battery on the device, and reduce the load on your server. However, if you do not control the server, it would be more complicated to achieve this, and then polling might be a good compromise.